# How to let the customer to continue shopping until the customer decides to stop? I don't know why is my loop is not working

Tags: java

You are required to write a Java program for a company that sells items of hardware
over the internet. Your program will list all the available hardware with their
corresponding prices for the customer to select. Your customer needs to input the selected
item and the quantity of that item. Your program should calculate the total price that the
customer needs to pay. The total price must also be inclusive of a 3% tax.
To make it easier for you, the company only sells 5 items, which you are given the
freedom to choose what item to sell, and how much is the price. The program will keep
on asking the customer to continue shopping until the customer decides to stop. At the
end of the session, the total price must be displayed to the user. (This is the question)

```
package courseworkitpl;
```

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CourseworkITPL {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int choice,quantity;
    double price,tax;
    String answer;

    int Macbook = 1;
    int Dell = 2;
    int ROG = 3;
    int Alienware = 4;
    int Razer = 5;

    int MacbookCost = 300;
    int DellCost = 250;
    int ROGCost = 395;
    int AlienwareCost = 400;
    int RazerCost = 350;
    tax=0.03;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Double totalSum = 0d;
```

do{

```
System.out.println("Welcome to my store, which computer do you like to purchase?");
System.out.println("1. Macbook");
System.out.println("2. Dell");
System.out.println("3. ROG");
System.out.println("4. Alienware");
System.out.println("5. Razer");

choice = keyboard.nextInt();

System.out.println("How much quantity you want to purchase?");
quantity = keyboard.nextInt();

if (choice == 1) {
    price = (MacbookCost*0.03+(MacbookCost*quantity));
} else if (choice == 2) {
     price = (DellCost*0.03+(DellCost*quantity));
} else if (choice == 3) {
    price = (ROGCost*0.03+(ROGCost*quantity));
}else if (choice == 4) {
     price = (AlienwareCost*0.03+(AlienwareCost*quantity));
}else if (choice == 5) {
     price = (RazerCost*0.03+(RazerCost*quantity));
}        
else  {
    price = 0;
    System.out.println("invalid choice");
}

totalSum = totalSum + price;

System.out.print("Do you want to continue yes/no?");
answer = keyboard.next();

} while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
System.out.println("That will be $" + totalSum + " with 3% of tax.");
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're a new contributor, so I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You may also want to read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11082165).

Answer (score 1):

You must change the do..while condition to

```
Double totalSum = 0d;

do{

    System.out.println("Welcome to my store, which computer do you like to purchase?");
    System.out.println("1. Macbook");
    System.out.println("2. Dell");
    System.out.println("3. ROG");
    System.out.println("4. Alienware");
    System.out.println("5. Razer");

    choice = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (choice == 1) {
        price = (MacbookCost*0.03+(MacbookCost));
    } else if (choice == 2) {
         price = (DellCost*0.03+(DellCost));
    } else if (choice == 3) {
        price = (ROGCost*0.03+(ROGCost));
    }else if (choice == 4) {
         price = (AlienwareCost*0.03+(AlienwareCost));
    }else if (choice == 5) {
         price = (RazerCost*0.03+(RazerCost));
    }        
    else  {
        price = 0;
        System.out.println("invalid choice");
    }

    totalSum = totalSum + price;

    System.out.print("Do you want to continue yes/no?");
    answer = keyboard.next();

    } while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
    System.out.println("That will be $" + totalSum + " with 3% of tax.");
```

For Objects we should use the equals method.

Check out these links for more details 
[link 1](https://www.javaworld.com/article/3305792/comparing-java-objects-with-equals-and-hashcode.html)
[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-java)

Comment: i tried and change the do and while condition. But is still not working

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: Can you update the question with the new code

Comment: its keep showing this That will be $360.5 with 3% of tax.
Do you want to continue yes/no?yes
That will be $360.5 with 3% of tax.
Do you want to continue yes/no?    its not looping

Comment: the new codes are updated

Comment: I have updated my answer. You will need to place the System.out.println statements inside the do while loop.

Comment: Okay. I have updated the improved code. Now, how can I total all the product that the customer chose if the customer doesn't want to continue purchasing

Comment: Create a double variable (say totalSum) outside the do..while loop. As the user keeps selecting the product add the new `price` to the totalSum. After the while loop print the total sum

Comment: Sry. I don't really know how?

Comment: @BrianFoo Kindly check my updated answer